# How to make a TW3ListBox scrollable in SMS?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

How do I make a TW3ListBox scrollable when the number of items is too large to display in the current display space?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TW3ListBox is scrollable by default. Just click and drag (or tap and drag) and it will scroll.